# Can't push array item to array data property - Vue Js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I a getting data from the laravel using this response :

```
$unserialize = unserialize($import->field_names);
return response()->json( $unserialize, 200 ) ;
```

Now on the Vue JS I can console the response using this :

```
console.log(response);
```

and It's showing the data in array (Check the red arrow mark):

[image]

Now, I have a `options` empty array property like this:

```
options : []
```

I want to push object data to this array with a key **value** and **text**. This key's value will be that response data single item. So, To do this, I am using this:

```
response.data.forEach((item, index) => {
    this.options.push({
        value: item,
        text: index
    });
});
```

but If I console

```
console.log(this.options);
```

I can not see the array of object to this **options** propery. I can see this:

[image]

can you tell me why? I want this options should store the item like this:

```
options: [
    { value: null, text: 'Please select some item' },
    { value: 'a', text: 'This is First option' },
    { value: 'b', text: 'Default Selected Option' },
    { value: 'c', text: 'This is another option' },
    { value: 'd', text: 'This one is disabled', disabled: true },
]
```

Update:

Console.log(response);

[image]

Comment: Can you post your more Vue code ? and as from your question I understood that options are filling with empty object right ?

Comment: @rohin-arka check my full vue code: https://codeshare.io/Pdn8ge. By default `options` will be empty array object but will be fill up like the example I posted.

Comment: Can you expand(eg click on the 0 index) the options and post. The browser console do not expand by default I wanted to know the options is array of empty object.

Comment: @rohin-arka `console.log(this.options) is https://prnt.sc/RfURA0Ko6PIs

Comment: Then it is fine right. Options has array of objects that has `value` and `text` property. The options array length is equivalent with response.data length.

Comment: @rohin-arka and another issue is it's not adding the array item value to that options array. It's adding item as text not as item's actual value.

Comment: That is weird. The `0` index of data has value `item` and as screenshot you posted options 0 index it has also value `item`. I think it is fine can you post expanding `1` or `2` index of options and check response.data 1 and 2 index. I think it is fine.

Comment: @rohin-arka Yes, you are right but why it's showing __ob__ (Observer)? Plz check the 2nd picture.

Comment: @rohin-arka Its should be showing like this : https://prnt.sc/00lmYzwn6yhz, right?

Comment: `observer` is a special property added by Vue and it is part of Vue reactivity system. Is that causing problem ?. If yes you can do `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.options)))`. You can check here for more details https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/292 and https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html

Comment: @rohin-arka Thank You So Much for Everything. I Understand :)

Comment: @rohin-arka would you please help me on this questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976337/how-to-use-html-input-select-checkbox-field-in-vue-js-loop-and-get-the-datas

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem could be in `this` keyword

you can modify your code in this way

```
this.options = [...this.options,
                ...response.data.map((item, index) => 
                     ({
                        value: item,
                        text: index
                      })
                )]
```

Comment: No. Its showing same output