# How to use HTML input, select, checkbox field in Vue JS loop and get the data's as Array

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have this for lop in my Vue JS application:

```
<b-form>    
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Import Field</th>
                <th>Project Field</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr
                v-for="(data, index) in projectFieldOptions"
                :key="index"
            >
                <td>
                    <b-form-input
                        class="basicInput"
                        v-model="data.text"
                    />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b-form-select
                        v-model="
                            selectedProjectOption
                        "
                        :options="
                            projectFieldOptions
                        "
                    />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b-form-checkbox
                        v-model="selectMap"
                        checked="false"
                        name="check-button"
                        switch
                        inline
                    >
                    </b-form-checkbox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <b-button
        variant="primary"
        type="submit"
        @click.prevent="validateEditMapping"
    >
        Next
    </b-button>
</b-form>
```

It's showing this output:

**You can see there are 3 fields:**

1. Import Field ( as input box )
2. Project Field ( as select dropdown )
3. Select ( as checkbox )

Now,

1. How can I get all the input, select and checkbox fields as array in Vue JS?
2. If I change the Project field dropdown then other dropdowm is also changed but it's should change my selected dropdown only. How can I solve it?

I want the output should like this:

```
[
   { item, imte, 0 },
   { description, description, 1},
    ....
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will start with the answer to the second question. Just like you have *data.text* assigned to v-model in **b-form-input**, you should make something similar for **b-form-select** and **b-form-checkbox** e.g.

```
<b-form-select
  v-model="data.selectedProjectOption"
  :options="projectFieldOptions"
/>
```

otherwise, you will have selectedProjectOption variable assigned to **every** **b-form-select** component, so if you change its value in one of them it will change the value in others as well.

For the first question, let's assume you *projectFieldOptions* look like this:

```
projectFieldOptions = [
  {text: 'text', selectedProjectOption: 'option', selectMap: 0, ...},
  {text: 'text1', selectedProjectOption: 'option1', selectMap: 1, ...},
  ...,
]
```

you can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) this array to receive desired output.

```js
const projectFieldOptions = [{
    text: 'text',
    selectedProjectOption: 'option',
    selectMap: 0
  },
  {
    text: 'text1',
    selectedProjectOption: 'option1',
    selectMap: 1
  },
]

const mappedArray = projectFieldOptions.map((e) => {
  return [e.text, e.selectedProjectOption, e.selectMap]
});

console.log(mappedArray);
```